# Is it possible to identify an item in a json dictionary's list, without hard-coding the list position?

Tags: python, json

I have this json dict:

```
output = {'data': {'entries': [{'rcsb_id': '1A17', 'rcsb_entry_info': {'assembly_count': 2, 'resolution_combined': [2.45]}, 'rcsb_accession_info': {'deposit_date': '1997-12-23T00:00:00Z'}, 'struct': {'pdbx_CASP_flag': None, 'pdbx_descriptor': 'SERINE/THREONINE PROTEIN PHOSPHATASE 5', 'pdbx_model_details': None, 'pdbx_model_type_details': None, 'title': 'TETRATRICOPEPTIDE REPEATS OF PROTEIN PHOSPHATASE 5'}, 'polymer_entities': [{'rcsb_entity_source_organism': [{'ncbi_scientific_name': 'Homo sapiens'}], 'rcsb_polymer_entity_container_identifiers': {'entry_id': '1A17', 'asym_ids': ['A'], 'auth_asym_ids': ['A'], 'entity_id': '1', 'reference_sequence_identifiers': [{'database_name': 'UniProt', 'database_accession': 'P53041'}]}, 'rcsb_polymer_entity': {'pdbx_mutation': None, 'pdbx_description': 'SERINE/THREONINE PROTEIN PHOSPHATASE 5'}, 'uniprots': [{'rcsb_id': 'P53041'}], 'entity_poly': {'rcsb_mutation_count': 0, 'rcsb_sample_sequence_length': 166}}], 'assemblies': [{'pdbx_struct_assembly_gen': [{'assembly_id': '1', 'asym_id_list': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']}], 'rcsb_struct_symmetry': [{'kind': 'Global Symmetry', 'symbol': 'D2', 'oligomeric_state': 'Homo 4-mer'}]}, {'pdbx_struct_assembly_gen': [{'assembly_id': '2', 'asym_id_list': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']}], 'rcsb_struct_symmetry': [{'kind': 'Global Symmetry', 'symbol': 'C2', 'oligomeric_state': 'Homo 2-mer'}]}]}]}}
```

If I want to pull out the rcsb_id, I know I can write:

```
print(output['data']['entries'][0]['rcsb_id'])
```

Is there a (possibly more pythonic) way to do this, where I do not have to hard-code in the 0, making the code possibly less prone to breaking (e.g. if say for example that item is moved elsewhere in the list in future?)

Comment: Is the real problem that an item in the `entries` list is moving rather than dictionary items? If so you can come up with a way to search the list for items that meet your criteria

Comment: you could use a loop and then pick the item satisfying the criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following. It will print the desired output, no matter the position of the dict inside the list.

```
print([i['rcsb_id'] for i in output['data']['entries'] if 'rcsb_id' in i][0])
```

Output:

```
1A17
```

I consider that 'rcsb_id' is found only in one dict, if it's found multiple times and you want all of them, you can remove the `[0]` index from my solution and you will a list of values